# SQL Server Database going into suspect mode after bulk insert and delete

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on an application that does a bulk copy of data from one table to another within the same database (using an Insert... Select) and then deleting the data from the source table. In production, sometimes the database goes into suspect mode and I have noticed that it always happens after this process is run. This process does this to multiple tables (around 20 tables). First it copies the relevant data from each table to its corresponding archive table. Then it deletes the relevant data from the source tables.

I checked on common reasons for this and there is enough free space in the disk and no antivirus software installed

Edit: Auto Close is disabled for the database

Comment: That's corruption, or a severe bug in SQL Server. CHECKDB!

Comment: This is something really serious with the database, for example running out of space doesn't do this

Comment: I forgot to mention that this only happens with some of the clients, although some run the same version without any issues. So far I haven't been able to recreate this in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that the transaction log might be broken. Did you check the serverlogs? Another idea could be that to set the emergency mode in your database and run a dbcc checkdb and take a look at the results.

I can't find a good reason for this behaviour. Maybe a bit code would help. I don't have any of this issues, even as I'm using such operations quite often.

Maybe another idea is this way:

1. Call procedure
2. Copy tables
3. Run Checkpoint
4. Clean tables on source

Comment: Thank you for the response. Right now I have no choice but to wait for it to happen again since I cannot recreate this in development and also this doesn't happen every time the process is run. I'll do this and reply as soon as it happens again. In the meantime, I'm also trying to recreate this on Dev / QA